# How to extend the dynamic time warping to 3D Cartesian space

Tags: clustering, distance, curves

I already searched the topics [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dynamic%20time%20warping) but couldn't figure out clearly what to do so I'm asking here.
I have thousands of fiber tracts (the outputs of a tractography algorithm on brain diffusion MRI) that I'd like to cluster them. Each tract is essentially a series of points in 3D Cartesian space. Not all the tracts have the same length and start and end point.
How can I extend the DTW to compute the similarity between fiber tracts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you asked!

There are two ways, DTWi and DTWd. I am 99% sure that for your application, you should do DTWd [a].

You may need to do endpoint invariance [b]. I can advise more if you show me some data.
eamonn

[a] http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Multi-Dimensional_DTW_Journal.pdf
[b] http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The data is the coordinates of the fiber tracts saved in a structure variable in MATLAB. How can I share it with you?